# pyschools topic 3 ex 9

Tags: python

I have made already 3 posts today about pyschools.com exercises i hope that's not too much. Anyway, the exercise asks me to write a function to convert the time to 24 hour format. 
Here's an example: >>> time24hr('12:34am') '0034hr'

My function, which works fine in my IDLE:

```
def time24hr(tstr):
    am_or_pm = tstr[-2:]
    first_numbers = tstr[0:2]
    last_numbers = tstr[3:5]
    if am_or_pm == "am":
        if first_numbers == '12':
            first_in_am12 = '00'
            return first_in_am12 + last_numbers + am_or_pm      
        else:
            return first_numbers + last_numbers + am_or_pm
    if am_or_pm == "pm":
        if first_numbers == '12':
            return first_numbers + last_numbers + am_or_pm
        elif int(first_numbers) > 9:
            ok = repr(int(first_numbers) + 12)
            return ok + last_numbers + am_or_pm
        elif int(first_numbers) <= 9:
            ok = repr(int(tstr[1]) + 12)
            return ok + last_numbers + am_or_pm
```

However, in the pyschools website, when i run the code, it gives me the following error : 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1:'
What does this mean ?

Comment: Look closely at the error message.  Even without understanding how the error message tells you what was wrong, you can probably see what is wrong from the part it tells you was in error.

Answer (score 4):

Actually your code is incorrect and you are not testing with full scale of test cases. Consider the following scenarios

```
>>> time24hr('2:34pm')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#855>", line 1, in <module>
    time24hr('2:34pm')
  File "<pyshell#849>", line 14, in time24hr
    elif int(first_numbers) > 9:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2:'
>>> time24hr('2:34am')
'2:4aam'
>>> time24hr('0:34am')
'0:4aam'
>>> time24hr('12am')
'00mam'
>>>
```

And you will see weird results

The reason is because, you have assumed that the input would always be in the format HH:MM[am|pm]. You should make your code flexible to accept other formats.

Try to use `split(':')` instead of `first_numbers = tstr[0:2]` and `last_numbers = tstr[3:5]`

Comment: I think the pyschools website assumed , that the function should be in format HH:MM . 
And also , it doesn't say i have wrong answers. It tells me that it can't compile it , because it finds an error in the line : elif int(first_numbers) > 9: 
Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
def time24hr(tstr):
    time=tstr.replace(':','')
    if 'am' in time:
        tim=int(time.replace('am',''))
    elif 'pm' in time:
        tim=int(time.replace('pm',''))
    mini=tim%100
    hour=tim//100
    if mini<10:
    mini='0'+str(mini)
    else:
        mini=str(mini)
    if 'am' in time:
        if hour<10:
            hour='0'+str(hour)
    elif hour==12:
        hour='0'+str(hour-12)
        time1=time.replace('am','')
        time1=str(hour)+str(mini)+'hr'
    elif 'pm' in time:
        if hour<12:
            hour=12+hour
        elif hour==12:
            hour=hour
    time1=time.replace('pm','')
    time1=str(hour)+str(mini)+'hr'
    return time1
```

it will work in pyschools

Comment: Can you add some explanatory text around this.